# Images are intersecting the citations

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents, floats

My figures are going between the reference lines, I even tried to place my figures with `[h!]` as well. But that is not working. What maybe the error here? And how to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: It may be the case that the figure is to large too fit on the page before the references, in which case I don't see an obvious solution.  If it should fit (which seems unlikely if `[h!]` doesn't work), check to make sure that `b` positioning is specified, or that the figure input occurs in the source file *before* anything else that will be placed on that page.  And be sure to position the figure input between paragraphs in the source file.  (This is *not* an Overleaf-specific problem.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton okay thanks.

Comment: I don't get the question. Which reference lines? Sometimes I'm temporally blind ... but could you mark the position you thing a misplacement is appearing?

Comment: @Formal_this Can you please add a small, but compilable test file to your question which allows us to reproduce the problem? Maybe a float barrier before the references could solve the problem.

Comment: @Suuuehgi ; yeah you can see citation number [10] and before that an image (FIG 8) is appearing.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz ; What's the compilable test file ? Is it the error log ?

Comment: @Formal_this No, a small latex test file which reproduces the problem. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/3225#3225

Comment: @Formal_this Jesus, now I got it. You mean the _bibliography entries_!
That took a while ... Try [`\clearpage`](https://latexref.xyz/_005cclearpage-_0026-_005ccleardoublepage.html) to place all figures before your new section begins. If page space is really sparse, try placing the figure higher / earlier in the source code. Have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/37806) if you want to know more about the placement algorithm. (And if it should not behave as a float, don't make it a float.)

Comment: You could also try to use a `\FloatBarrier` from the `placeins` package: https://ctan.org/pkg/placeins